# Databricks MLFlow AutoML XGBoost can't predict_proba()

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, databricks, xgboost, mlflow

I used AutoML in Databricks Notebooks for a binary classification problem and the winning model flavor was XGBoost (big surprise).

The outputted model is of this variety:

```
mlflow.pyfunc.loaded_model:
      artifact_path: model
      flavor: mlflow.sklearn
      run_id: 123456789
```

Any idea why when I use `model.predict_proba(X)`, I get this response?

`AttributeError: 'PyFuncModel' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'`

I know it is possible to get the probabilities because ROC/AUC is a metric used for tuning the model. Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with catboost model.
The way I solved it was by saving the artifacts in a local dir

````
import os
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient
client = MlflowClient()
local_dir = "/dbfs/FileStore/user/models"
local_path = client.download_artifacts('run_id', "model", local_dir)```

```model_path = '/dbfs/FileStore/user/models/model/model.cb'
model = CatBoostClassifier()
model = model.load_model(model_path)
model.predict_proba(test_set)```
````